# Shim UEFI MOK management countdown key press ignored

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

I have a system with Windows 10 with UEFI, and secure boot enabled. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a dual boot configuration. I installed a driver in Ubuntu which required setting up of an MOK and a new password.

After rebooting, the UEFI MOK management screen is shown, which instructs the user to press any key to enter MOK management. However, pressing any key does not work, the countdown gets over and the screen proceeds to the grub menu. Further reboots do not bring up the Shim UEFI countdown screen.

I tried uninstalling and installing the driver followed by rebooting, but the issue persists. Is there another way to manually enter MOK management to confirm the password? Or should I just disable secure boot?

Comment: Try using another USB keyboard or a different USB port for your keyboard.  Try toggling the USB Legacy Enable/Disable in UEFI/BIOS Setup.